# Merge tags [0xdbe] and [datagrip]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

JetBrains [released last december](http://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2015/12/16/datagrip-1-0-formerly-0xdbe-a-new-ide-for-dbs-and-sql/) [datagrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagrip). Before that (during the beta test), it was called [0xdbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/0xdbe).

There are stil questions tagged with the old name (currently 15). Both tags should be merged and [datagrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagrip) should survive.

Comment: Why merging 15 tags? Wouldn't be more easy just to retag them?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like somebody retagged these questions. This is done.